# How to execute UNC based batch file in Windows task scheduler?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a batch file I need to run in Windows task scheduler.

```
\\sharedrive\operations\daily\master.bat
```

It appears that I am having issues mastering Windows tasck scheduler to execute this file.

I have tried several things in the action tab:

1. Putting in `\\sharedrive\operations\daily` in the **Start in** field and `master.bat` in the **Program** field which results in `cannot access directory` error.
2. Putting in `\\sharedrive\operations\daily\master.bat` in the **Program** field and got a successful error.

How do I set this up correctly so I can call UNC based batch files as if they were local?

I realize that mapped drives are a problem, so here I am.

Comment: Use a **backslash** as required as part of volume names, for example, the `"C:\"` in `"C:\path\file"` or the `"\\server\share"` in `"\\server\share\path\file"` for Universal Naming Convention (UNC) names. A **UNC name**  always start with **two backslash characters** (`"\\"`).

Comment: sorry.  That's how it's set.  My bad...I'm correcting the question....the question is wrong.  everything is in backslash

Comment: The scheduled task needs credentials from a user that has permissions to that unc path.